# Showing data from mysql database in jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, arrays, json, data-binding

```
// get data and store in a json array
$from = 0;
$to = 200;
$query = "SELECT id, motiv, nume_client, data_inreg, ora_inreg, ora_preluare, ora_rezolvare, operator_preluare, desk FROM septembrie LIMIT ?,?";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$result->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
$result->execute();
/* bind result variables */
$result->bind_result($id, $motiv, $nume_client, $data_inreg, $ora_inreg, $ora_preluare, $ora_rezolvare, $operator_preluare, $desk);
/* fetch values */
while ($result->fetch())
    {
    $orders[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'motiv' => $motiv,
        'nume_client' => $nume_client,
        'data_inreg' => $data_inreg,
        'ora_inreg' => $ora_inreg,
        'ora_preluare' => $ora_preluare,
        'ora_rezolvare' => $ora_rezolvare,
        'operator_preluare' => $operator_preluare,
        'desk' => $desk
    );
    }
echo json_encode($orders);
/* close statement */
$result->close();
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

If the `$to` is set to `2000`, it will not show the data from database. If i put `200`, it will show my data. Anyone has a clue about this? I cannot put a value higher than `200` because the entries from database will not be shown.

Comment: Are you using POST or GET?

Comment: I am using a `<script>` which calls the above file. There are no POST or GET.

Comment: You are not bringing this in via ajax?  you are doing a `<script src = "thefile.php">`  ?  because that isn't JS....